# Get Markers from ClusterManager

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-utils

I am using ClusterManager to group the markers in android application.

I want to get list of markers and use

```
mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers();
```

This method returns no markers when we zoom out.and returns markers only when zoom in to show all markers.is there any way to get all markers ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? When you say you want to get a list of markers do you mean all the cluster markers? (because a cluster on the map is a single marker with a number on it) or do you want a list of markers a cluster has when clusted? If you say ClusterMarker I will assume you mean the marker on the map representing a cluster.

Comment: @Losin'Me i mean list of markers within a cluster(list of markers a cluster has when clusted).

Comment: From a cluster that you have clicked? or just all the clusters?

Comment: All clusters. I need this because i have to change marker icon depending on user input.Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Wait what happens if you use mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection() instead? you wanted the list of cluster markers no?

Comment: mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection() returns one item if one cluster is shown.The cluster says 100+ and i want that 100+ items.Sorry for late reply

Comment: But if there is 2 clusters both with 100, you want to get all 200 in one go!?

Comment: hi , Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
java.util.Collection<Marker> userCollection = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().mMarkers;       
ArrayList<Marker> userList = new ArrayList<Marker>(userCollection);
Log.d("list", "size: " + userList.size());
```